# Consultar cantidad y valor de items usados

Tags: sql, revisión-de-código, ms-access

Tengo una tabla llamada *Modificadores*:

Esta es la estructura:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   ModId   |   ModText     |   AdditionalCost      |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     58    |   RANCH       |   2000                |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     86    |   GUACAMOLE   |   500                 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     52    |   CEBOLLA     |   0                   |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     87    |   QUESO       |   150                 |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Tengo otra tabla llamada "Órdenes", cuya estructura es la siguiente:

```
---------------------------------------------
|   OrderId     |   OrderDateTime           |
---------------------------------------------
|   20001       |   2017-06-01 00:00:00     |
---------------------------------------------
|   20001       |   2017-06-01 00:00:00     |
---------------------------------------------
|   15224       |   2017-06-02 00:00:00     |
---------------------------------------------
|   13501       |   2017-06-03 00:00:00     |
---------------------------------------------
```

Tengo otra tabla llamada "Transacciones", cuya estructura es la siguiente:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   TransaccionID   |   Mod1ID      |   Mod2ID      |   Mod3ID      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1             |               |   86          |   87          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|     2             |   58          |               |               |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|     3             |   87          |   52          |               |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|     4             |               |   58          |               |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

La tabla *Transacciones* tiene estas características:

- Las columnas van desde **Mod1ID** hasta **Mod20ID**.
- Como se puede ver en el ejemplo, los Ids de la tabla *Modificadores* se ubican en las diferentes columnas **ModXID** de *Transacciones*.
- Una Transacción puede estar compuesto de uno o mas modificadores.

Lo que busco es crear una consulta en [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) para obtener el siguiente resultado:

- Obtener la cantidad de modificadores usados en un rango de fecha.

Ejemplo del **resultado deseado**:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|   Modificador |   Cantidad    |   Valor       |
-------------------------------------------------
|   RANCH       |   2           |   4000        |
-------------------------------------------------
|   GUACAMOLE   |   5           |   2500        |
-------------------------------------------------
|   CEBOLLA     |   7           |   0           |
-------------------------------------------------
|   QUESO       |   4           |   600         |
-------------------------------------------------
```

---

Tengo hecha esta consulta en [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) *(la cual obtiene los resultados esperados)*, pero me gustaría saber si hay una mejor manera de obtener los mismos resultados "es decir, los resultados esperados":

> **NOTA:** Para abreviar, esta consulta solo usa las columnas Mod1ID,
>   Mod2Id, Mod3ID y Mod4ID:

```
SELECT
    t.MenuModifierText AS [Modificador],
    COUNT(*) AS [Cantidad],
    (SELECT MenuModCost.AdditionalCost FROM MenuModifiers AS MenuModCost WHERE MenuModCost.MenuModifierID = t.MenuModifierID) AS ValorMod,
    (SELECT MenuModCost.AdditionalCost FROM MenuModifiers AS MenuModCost WHERE MenuModCost.MenuModifierID = t.MenuModifierID) * COUNT(*) AS [Valor]
FROM(
    SELECT MENUMODS.MenuModifierText, MENUMODS.MenuModifierID
    FROM (OrderTransactions AS ORDTRDS INNER JOIN OrderHeaders AS ORDHRD
    ON ORDTRDS.OrderID = ORDHRD.OrderID) INNER JOIN MenuModifiers AS MENUMODS
    ON MENUMODS.MenuModifierID = ORDTRDS.Mod1ID
    WHERE ORDHRD.OrderDateTime BETWEEN #06/21/2017 00:00:00# AND #06/22/2017 23:59:59#
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MENUMODS.MenuModifierText, MENUMODS.MenuModifierID
    FROM (OrderTransactions AS ORDTRDS INNER JOIN OrderHeaders AS ORDHRD
    ON ORDTRDS.OrderID = ORDHRD.OrderID) INNER JOIN MenuModifiers AS MENUMODS
    ON MENUMODS.MenuModifierID = ORDTRDS.Mod2ID
    WHERE ORDHRD.OrderDateTime BETWEEN #06/21/2017 00:00:00# AND #06/22/2017 23:59:59#
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MENUMODS.MenuModifierText, MENUMODS.MenuModifierID
    FROM (OrderTransactions AS ORDTRDS INNER JOIN OrderHeaders AS ORDHRD
    ON ORDTRDS.OrderID = ORDHRD.OrderID) INNER JOIN MenuModifiers AS MENUMODS
    ON MENUMODS.MenuModifierID = ORDTRDS.Mod3ID
    WHERE ORDHRD.OrderDateTime BETWEEN #06/21/2017 00:00:00# AND #06/22/2017 23:59:59#
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MENUMODS.MenuModifierText, MENUMODS.MenuModifierID
    FROM (OrderTransactions AS ORDTRDS INNER JOIN OrderHeaders AS ORDHRD
    ON ORDTRDS.OrderID = ORDHRD.OrderID) INNER JOIN MenuModifiers AS MENUMODS
    ON MENUMODS.MenuModifierID = ORDTRDS.Mod4ID
    WHERE ORDHRD.OrderDateTime BETWEEN #06/21/2017 00:00:00# AND #06/22/2017 23:59:59#
) AS t
GROUP BY t.MenuModifierID, t.MenuModifierText;
```

Comment: Creo que la estructura está muy mal planteada, y por poco que puedas te aconsejo que la modifiques. Yo usaría la tabla [Transacciones] con tan solo dos campos [TransaccionID] y [ModID], y así podrías crear tantos modificadores como quieras para 1 transacción. 
Imagina lo simple que sería obtener la cantidad de modificadores:
Select ModID, Count(*) From [Transacciones] GROUP BY ModID
A esta consulta simplemente habría que hacer join con las tablas de órdenes para filtrar fechas, y con la tabla de modificadores para obtener el nombre de cada ModID

Comment: @BeniGls gracias por tu comentario, pero, esta es una base de datos que usa un software al que le estamos haciendo soporte (no podemos modificar la estructura y la relación de las tablas; podemos crear nuevas, pero el software principal es quien escribe en esas columnas de modificadores)., creo que tu comentario sería mas una respuesta que puede servirle a alguien mas. Saludos.

Comment: ok. la añadiré como respuesta, juntamente con alguna alternativa programable. espero que eso pueda servir

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "mejor manera"? ¿Menos líneas, más rápido, ...?

Comment: @Rubén todo lo necesario para que sea mejor. No soy experto en SQL, pero no creo que la consulta sea eficiente.

Comment: "todo lo necesario para que sea mejor" podría dar pie a respuestas basadas en opiniones y ser demasiado amplio para ser abordado en un respuesta completa en SOes. Me parece que deberías escoger un aspecto y enfocar tu pregunta a eso.

Answer (score 0):

Ese query es el correcto.

Access funciona diferente de los lenguajes de base de datos con el estándar ANSI SQL (SQL Server, Oracle, etc), por lo tanto un simple Group By lo convierte en algo complejo, en mi experiencia cuando utilizo Access lo hago mediante el Wizard ya que al hacerlo manual en ocasiones el resultado no es el esperado, además de que la sintaxis es hasta cierto punto tediosa.

Propiamente Access es un RDBMS no una base de datos, de ahí parte la diferencia de la sintaxis y la forma en la que trabaja.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la estructura está muy mal planteada, y por poco que puedas te aconsejo que la modifiques.

Yo usaría la tabla [Transacciones] con tan solo dos campos: [TransaccionID] y [ModID], y así podrías crear tantos modificadores como quieras para 1 transacción.

Imagina lo simple que sería obtener la cantidad de modificadores:

```
Select ModID, Count(*) From [Transacciones] GROUP BY ModID
```

A esta consulta simplemente habría que hacer join con las tablas de órdenes para filtrar fechas, y con la tabla de modificadores para obtener el nombre de cada ModID

Aunque existe la posibilidad de que no puedas modificar la estructura. 
En ese caso, yo optaría por otra manera de hacerlo. No obstante, se necesita algo de programación.

Te voy a añadir alguna idea programada que tengo en la cabeza. Pero TEN EN CUENTA que he programado sin pasarlo por el validador de vba, así que puede tener todo tipo de errores. Aun así, si tienes nociones de programación, creo que entenderás bien el concepto, que es lo que mas me interesa transmitir:

1) Creamos una tabla temporal con la información que te puse antes:
    Nombre de la tabla: [Transacciones TEMPORAL]
    Campo1: TransaccionID
    Campo2: ModID

2) Programamos un pequeño método. Algo así:
    Public Sub GenerarTransacciones(ByVal Fecha1 As Date, ByVal Fecha2 As Date)
        CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM [TransaccionesTEMP]"

```
    For I = 1 To 20
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [TransaccionesTEMP](TransaccionID, ModID)" & _
            " SELECT ORDTRDS.OrderID, MENUMODS.MenuModifierID " & _
            " FROM (OrderTransactions AS ORDTRDS INNER JOIN OrderHeaders AS ORDHRD " & _
            " ON ORDTRDS.OrderID = ORDHRD.OrderID) INNER JOIN MenuModifiers AS MENUMODS " & _
            " ON MENUMODS.MenuModifierID = ORDTRDS.Mod" & I & "ID " & _
            " WHERE ORDHRD.OrderDateTime BETWEEN #" & Format(Fecha1, "mm/dd/yy") & "# AND #" & Format(Fecha2, "mm/dd/yy") & "#"
    Next I

    'Aquí ya tendrías la tabla que te comenté al principio. Con ella ahora se pueden hacer consultas mas elegantes, ya sea por código o usando consultas
End Sub
```

Podría pasar que el volumen de datos sea tan grande que la carga de datos sea mas lenta que la consulta. 
En ese caso, podrías generar la consulta desde código, lo cual no te soluciona ese engorrosa consulta SQL, pero si que te facilita que se cree usando código, lo cual te evita copiar/pegar la consulta una y otra vez:

```
Public Sub GenerarConsultaTransacciones(ByVal Fecha1 As Date, ByVal Fecha2 As Date)
    Dim ConsultaSQL As String

    ConsultaSQL = _
        " SELECT t.MenuModifierText AS [Modificador], COUNT(*) AS [Cantidad]," & _
        "(SELECT MenuModCost.AdditionalCost FROM MenuModifiers AS MenuModCost WHERE MenuModCost.MenuModifierID = t.MenuModifierID) AS ValorMod," & _
        "(SELECT MenuModCost.AdditionalCost FROM MenuModifiers AS MenuModCost WHERE MenuModCost.MenuModifierID = t.MenuModifierID) * COUNT(*) AS [Valor]" & _
        "FROM("

    For I = 1 To 20
        ConsultaSQL = ConsultaSQL & _
            " INSERT INTO [TransaccionesTEMP](TransaccionID, ModID)" & _
            " SELECT MENUMODS.MenuModifierText, MENUMODS.MenuModifierID " & _
            " FROM (OrderTransactions AS ORDTRDS INNER JOIN OrderHeaders AS ORDHRD " & _
            " ON ORDTRDS.OrderID = ORDHRD.OrderID) INNER JOIN MenuModifiers AS MENUMODS " & _
            " ON MENUMODS.MenuModifierID = ORDTRDS.Mod" & I & "ID " & _
            " WHERE ORDHRD.OrderDateTime BETWEEN #" & Format(Fecha1, "mm/dd/yy") & "# AND #" & Format(Fecha2, "mm/dd/yy") & "#"
        If I < 20 Then ConsultaSQL = ConsultaSQL & " UNION ALL "
    Next I

    ConsultaSQL = ConsultaSQL & ") AS t GROUP BY t.MenuModifierID, t.MenuModifierText"

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "Consulta TRansacciones"
    On Error GoTo 0
    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "Consulta Transacciones", ConsultaSQL
End Sub
```