# Suma sin distinct y que no me sume datos de otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT 
t.SI_Articulo, 
m.SI_Descripcion,  
t.SI_UM,
(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END) SI_OV, 
COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(c.SI_Ubicacion,t.SI_Ubicacion)) SI_Ubicacion, 
SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) SI_Existencia, 
(CASE WHEN SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad)END )SI_Cantidad,
(CASE WHEN SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) IS NULL THEN 0 - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) 
ELSE SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) END ) SI_Dif,
(CASE WHEN SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia)* m.SI_Costo_Promedio IS NULL 
THEN 0 - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) * m.SI_Costo_Promedio ELSE SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia)* m.SI_Costo_Promedio END) SI_Dif_Dinero 
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo 
LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo AND c.SI_Num_Inventario = 1
LEFT JOIN SI_Consecutivo cs ON cs.SI_Num_Inventario = c.SI_Num_Inventario
GROUP BY t.SI_Articulo, 
         m.SI_Descripcion, 
         t.SI_UM, 
         (CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END),
         m.SI_Costo_Promedio
```

En la cual estoy teniendo el error de que al sumar `SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) SI_Existencia` se metira a las tablas de `SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD` y `SI_Conteo c` y me trae una suma muy grande y si le pongo el `DISTINCT` solo me va a decir que suma uno ya que el articulo esta repetido en la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sorry Lamak

Comment: Eduard, tu problema no es en ese cálculo en particular, hay un problema de fondo en que las tablas se están cruzando en forma incorrecta. Por lo que solucionar este tema puntual igual sólo es un parche, y el día de mañana te vas a encontrar con otro problema. Para poder ayudarte realmente tendríamos que saber la estructura de las tablas, ejemplo de datos, lógica de lo que quieres obtener **como resultado final** y datos de ejemplo del resultado deseado

Comment: Voy a intentar explicar todo.

Comment: El problema con esta clase de consultas que agrupan muchos datos y tienen muchas restricciones, es que para hacerlas, se hacen por tramos.. tomando casi te diria de a una columna por vez, verificando los resultados de ella, y luego yendo a la siguiente. tratar de solucionar un query que tiene 30 columnas calculadas, mas X cantidad de joins, va a generar mas errores de los que tiene. Esto se hace por pasos y despacito... comprobando en cada iteracion que los resultados sean correctos, y muchas veces utilizando subquerys para resolverlo

Comment: es mas.. te puedo asegurar que quien venga atras tuyo, no va a poder ni tocar ese query de lo complejo que es...

Comment: @Eduard, te sugiero [edit] tu pregunta desglosando la consulta, mira por ejemplo [mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/80591/78). Allí describo la tabla, proporciono datos de prueba y muestro los resultados que deseo obtener. La verdad, así como está tu pregunta es complicada que los usuarios comprendan tu problema.